# Fixed height table irrespective of the available space. Table become scrollable

Tags: html, css, html-table, scroll, bootstrap-4

I want my table to have a fixed dynamic height, so I can scroll and it does not expand.

So I have this bootstrap row & 2 columns. I want the table or the left column to have the height of the height needed for the right column.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col">
    <table class="table table-sm table-light table-striped">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi, cupiditate!</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi, cupiditate!</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi, cupiditate!</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi, cupiditate!</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi, cupiditate!</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi, cupiditate!</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi, cupiditate!</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi, cupiditate!</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi, cupiditate!</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi, cupiditate!</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi, cupiditate!</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi, cupiditate!</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="col">
    <h3>&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur earum labore molestiae? Amet facilis
        minima nobis saepe ut voluptatem voluptates! Alias autem error explicabo hic molestiae non pariatur qui repellendus?</h3>

    <p>&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam expedita id illum ipsam molestiae quam, qui recusandae sed sint voluptate. Accusantium amet atque, cumque error est facere harum libero magnam molestias nam nemo, nobis omnis perspiciatis suscipit tenetur ullam veritatis voluptates voluptatibus? Amet blanditiis, consequatur cupiditate, ea earum eius fugiat illo in ipsa itaque magni nemo nihil quaerat quia ratione saepe, sunt ullam vel. Accusamus ad adipisci architecto blanditiis cupiditate debitis doloribus dolorum error facere hic laboriosam, laudantium magni maxime, molestias mollitia necessitatibus, nisi quibusdam quis quos veritatis. Assumenda cum cumque facere nobis quaerat sed, sequi voluptatem! Ab, dolores odit.</p>
</div>
```

In this example the table just expands downwards if I add more rows. But I want the table to skip expanding when the height is at the height of the right column and scroll in stead.

I use **bootstrap** for styling.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want the table to respect the height of the smaller column, we need JavaScript...

We take the height of the right column and applies it to the table, letting a scrollbar to help with viewing the contents

working **snippet** below:

```js
$(window).on("resize", function() {
  $(".col:nth-child(1)").css('height', $(".actualContents").height());
  $(".col:nth-child(1)").css('display', 'block');
  $(".col:nth-child(1)").css('overflow-y', 'scroll');
}).resize();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <table class="table table-sm table-light table-striped">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi, cupiditate!</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi, cupiditate!</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi, cupiditate!</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi, cupiditate!</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi, cupiditate!</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi, cupiditate!</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi, cupiditate!</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi, cupiditate!</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi, cupiditate!</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi, cupiditate!</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi, cupiditate!</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi, cupiditate!</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="actualContents">
        <h3>&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur earum labore molestiae? Amet facilis minima nobis saepe ut voluptatem voluptates! Alias autem error explicabo hic molestiae non pariatur qui repellendus?</h3>

        <p>&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam expedita id illum ipsam molestiae quam, qui recusandae sed sint voluptate. Accusantium amet atque, cumque error est facere harum libero magnam molestias nam nemo, nobis omnis perspiciatis
          suscipit tenetur ullam veritatis voluptates voluptatibus? Amet blanditiis, consequatur cupiditate, ea earum eius fugiat illo in ipsa itaque magni nemo nihil quaerat quia ratione saepe, sunt ullam vel. Accusamus ad adipisci architecto blanditiis
          cupiditate debitis doloribus dolorum error facere hic laboriosam, laudantium magni maxime, molestias mollitia necessitatibus, nisi quibusdam quis quos veritatis. Assumenda cum cumque facere nobis quaerat sed, sequi voluptatem! Ab, dolores odit.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering if there was a way to do this with css alone?

Comment: flex can take the bigger column and adjust the rest of match it... but I don't think there is anything OOTB to make it so with the height of a specific column which is not the tallest

Answer (score 0):

As the previous one is in jQuery (wich I don't use) I shall answer in JS:
const rightColumn = document.getElementById("rightColumn").firstElementChild;

const table = document.getElementById("actualContents");

```
window.addEventListener("resize", (evt) => {
    resize();
});

function resize() {
    table.style.height = rightColumn.clientHeight;
    table.style.overflowY = "scroll";
}
resize();

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <table class="table table-sm table-light table-striped">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi, cupiditate!</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi, cupiditate!</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi, cupiditate!</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi, cupiditate!</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi, cupiditate!</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi, cupiditate!</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi, cupiditate!</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi, cupiditate!</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi, cupiditate!</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi, cupiditate!</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi, cupiditate!</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi, cupiditate!</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div id="actualContents">
        <h3>&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur earum labore molestiae? Amet facilis minima nobis saepe ut voluptatem voluptates! Alias autem error explicabo hic molestiae non pariatur qui repellendus?</h3>

        <p>&Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam expedita id illum ipsam molestiae quam, qui recusandae sed sint voluptate. Accusantium amet atque, cumque error est facere harum libero magnam molestias nam nemo, nobis omnis perspiciatis
          suscipit tenetur ullam veritatis voluptates voluptatibus? Amet blanditiis, consequatur cupiditate, ea earum eius fugiat illo in ipsa itaque magni nemo nihil quaerat quia ratione saepe, sunt ullam vel. Accusamus ad adipisci architecto blanditiis
          cupiditate debitis doloribus dolorum error facere hic laboriosam, laudantium magni maxime, molestias mollitia necessitatibus, nisi quibusdam quis quos veritatis. Assumenda cum cumque facere nobis quaerat sed, sequi voluptatem! Ab, dolores odit.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```